# How to turn a generator into generator of generator of N elements

Tags: python, generator

Right now I have this python function:

```
def groupBy(iterable, N):
    ret = []
    count = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if count < N:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            yield ret
            count = 1
            ret = []
        ret.append(item)
    yield ret
```

`>>> [iter for iter in groupBy(xrange(25), 10)]`

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

The problems are:

- I have no way to know `iterable` and `N` before hand
- Futher processing on each item on `iter` is needed

I would like to be memory efficient.
So instead of yield a list in `groupBy` function, is it possible to yield another generator?

For the same input `[iter for iter in groupBy(xrange(25), 10)]`, return something like

```
[<generator object subGenerator at 0x000001000>,
 <generator object subGenerator at 0x000002000>,
 <generator object subGenerator at 0x000003000>]
```

Comment: `I would like to be memory efficient` always a good goal, but remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil. Try your algorithm out in expected, worst case, and engineered attacks to see if it fails.